# Eventstudies package r phys2eventtime null

Tags: r, error-handling, package, character

I am using the eventstudies package in R and I am struggling to replicate the eventsudy function which is used as an example in the package as below:

```r
# Event study without adjustment
es <- eventstudy(firm.returns = StockPriceReturns,
event.list = SplitDates,
event.window = 7,
type = "None",
to.remap = TRUE,
remap = "cumsum",
inference = TRUE,
inference.strategy = "bootstrap")
```

I use my own data for `StockPriceReturns` and `SplitDates` and even though I have tried to make them of the same format, type etc of those above I think this is where it is failing. The message I am getting is:

> Error in phys2eventtime(z = returns$firm.returns, events =
> event.list[i,  :  events$name should a character class. In addition:
> Warning message: In is.na(events$name) :   is.na() applied to
> non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Any help would be much appreciated.